# Composition in solidity using sol2uml

Tags: design-patterns, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I have the following code snippet:

```
contract Bar{

}
contract Foo { 
     Bar bar = new Bar(); 

}
```

When I am generating the class diagram from sol2uml I get the following diagram:

[image: Class Diagram]

I want to have a composition relation between Foo and Bar class.
[image]

I am not sure if this code is correct for this relationship or there is some problem with sol2uml.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, what you do is a composition relationship. Composition is a "has-a" relationship. The lifetime of the `Bar` is dependent on the lifetime of the whole `Foo`.

[As t2informatik says:](https://t2informatik.de/en/smartpedia/uml-composition/)

> A composition is visualized with a line between the model elements and
> a **filled diamond** on the side of the whole.

So it looks like tool generated incorrect diagram.

Comment: Shouldn't the symbol between Foo and Bar be a diamond sign rather an arrow?

Comment: @Maliha yeah, you are right, composition should be shown as **filled diamond**. Please, see my updated answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a has-a relationship. Basically, it is an association type between Bar and Foo. For instance, if you have a relationship A --> (local) B (plantuml), then you have the following code (Java).

```
public class A {
     public void f() { //local behavior
         B b = new B();
     }
}
```

When you have a composition, you need to think like when you delete the Bar, a n abstract type of the Foo class cannot